# WebFlux How to Chain Queries In Functional Non Blocking Way

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I am new to functional paradigm, wondering how to go about doing some querying before creating a new object?

```
@Override
public Mono<Order> create(CreateOrderRequest specs) {

    //itemRepository.findAll(specs.getItemCodes()) //returns Flux<Item>


    final Order newOrder = new Order(items);
    return orderRepository.insert(newOrder)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Failed to create order")));
}
```

How do I chain the commented code in a non blocking way? The query returns `Flux<Item>` while Order constructor requires a `List<Item>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`collectList()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) method, which will change your `Flux<Item>` into a `Mono<List<Item>>`.

After that, you can use the [`map()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method to convert your `List<Item>` into an `Order` object, and the [`flatMap()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method to get the saved result.

For example:

```java
return itemRepository
    .findAll(specs.getItemCodes())
    .collectList()
    .map(Order::new)
    .flatMap(orderRepository::insert)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Failed to create order")));
```